# Como cambiar un texto al ingresar valores en un input JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente tengo un input que recibe números, y este a su ves debe realizar cálculos y mostrarlos en etiquetas de texto en el HTML lo que hice fue lo siguiente pero no me funciona correctamente, cuando se escriba el input muestre los cálculos, y cambie el texto en las etiquetas `<li>`

```js
//Definiión de varibles para el uso del simulador
//Capturando los elementos correspondientes a su id para la muestra de resultados
let valorCredito = $('#inputValor').html($("#valorSlider").val());
let numeroDias = $('#inputValor1').html($("#valorSlider1").val());
let textoInteres = $('#valorInteres');
let textoSeguro = $('#valorSeguro');
let textoEstudio = $('#valorEstudio')
let textoPlataforma = $('#valorPlataforma');
let textoIva = $('#valorIva');
//Valores numericos
let interesCobrar = 2.2;
let seguroCobrar = 0.6;
let estudioCobrar = 10000;
let plataformaCobrar = 32000;
//Calculo correspondiente al iva
let ivaCobrar = ((estudioCobrar + plataformaCobrar) * 19) / 100;
//Fin de valriables
//Codigo decimales

$('#inputValor').change(function () {
    let inputValor = $('#inputValor').val($(this).val());
    let valorInteres = Math.round(($(this).val() * interesCobrar) / 100);
    let valorSeguro = Math.round(($(this).val() * seguroCobrar) / 100);
    textoInteres.text('$' + valorInteres);
    textoSeguro.text('$' + valorSeguro);
    textoEstudio.text('$' + estudioCobrar);
    textoPlataforma.text('$' + plataformaCobrar);
    textoIva.text('$' + Math.round(ivaCobrar));
    $('.valoresIntereses').css("padding", "0px 10px");
    $('.valoresIntereses').css("margin", "0px 40px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="inputValor" placeholder="Monto Maximo es de 1.000.000"/>

<div class="valoresIntereses">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p id="valorInteres">2.2% E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorSeguro">0,06 E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorEstudio">0,06 E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorPlataforma">0,06 E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorIva">2.9 E.M</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Me temo que sin el **HTML** asociado a tu **JS** falta la mitad del caso para poder montar un ejemplo mínimo.

Comment: Listo, mil disculpas por no poner el código asociado.

Comment: Nos faltan las variables: interesCobrar, seguroCobrar, valorInteres, valorSeguro, estudioCobrar, plataformaCobrar, ivaCobrar. ¿De dónde las sacas? ¿Dónde las inicializas?

Comment: Mil disculpas corregido, las inicializo al comienzo.

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún error la consola? ¿El `<input>` no hace nada al cambiar su valor? Algo más concreto de lo que te ocurre sería ideal.

Comment: No me arroja ningun error, la idea es que yo escribo un valor en el input, a medida que escribo o dejo de escribir, el jquery haces los calculos y me muestra los resultados en las etiquetas <li>

Comment: El evento `change()` se dispara en momento que el `<input>` pierde el foco. Si lo que deseas es que calcule en cada número que se inserte o se quite debes usar el evento `keyup()` como te han respondido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es simple, tan solo cambia `$('#inputValor').change(..` por `$('#inputValor').keyup(..`, y eso debería de funcionarte:

```js
//Definiión de varibles para el uso del simulador
//Capturando los elementos correspondientes a su id para la muestra de resultados
let valorCredito = $('#inputValor').html($("#valorSlider").val());
let numeroDias = $('#inputValor1').html($("#valorSlider1").val());
let textoInteres = $('#valorInteres');
let textoSeguro = $('#valorSeguro');
let textoEstudio = $('#valorEstudio')
let textoPlataforma = $('#valorPlataforma');
let textoIva = $('#valorIva');
//Valores numericos
let interesCobrar = 2.2;
let seguroCobrar = 0.6;
let estudioCobrar = 10000;
let plataformaCobrar = 32000;
//Calculo correspondiente al iva
let ivaCobrar = ((estudioCobrar + plataformaCobrar) * 19) / 100;
//Fin de valriables
//Codigo decimales

$('#inputValor').keyup(function () {
    let inputValor = $('#inputValor').val($(this).val());
    let valorInteres = Math.round(($(this).val() * interesCobrar) / 100);
    let valorSeguro = Math.round(($(this).val() * seguroCobrar) / 100);
    textoInteres.text('$' + valorInteres);
    textoSeguro.text('$' + valorSeguro);
    textoEstudio.text('$' + estudioCobrar);
    textoPlataforma.text('$' + plataformaCobrar);
    textoIva.text('$' + Math.round(ivaCobrar));
    $('.valoresIntereses').css("padding", "0px 10px");
    $('.valoresIntereses').css("margin", "0px 40px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="inputValor" placeholder="Monto Maximo es de 1.000.000"/>

<div class="valoresIntereses">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p id="valorInteres">2.2% E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorSeguro">0,06 E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorEstudio">0,06 E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorPlataforma">0,06 E.M</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p id="valorIva">2.9 E.M</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```